# Loading/launching activex control using NPAPI

Tags: activex

I have a mozilla browser(this browser is developed for windows based mobile handsets).I have used NP plugin for rendering flash content on my browser.There are NPAPIs which can be used for controlling the flash window properties.I have used NPAPIs for getting the flash contents from the browser and rendering it on the browser.
Now I want to launch activeX control using the NPAPI.This is required for rendering flash in wince platform which uses activeX to render flash content on nay web page.Does any one know how to launch an activeX control using NPAPI so that the NPPlugin which is implemented for windows phone also works on wince platform.
Thanks in advance,
Snehal

Answer (score 1):

Check out: http://code.google.com/p/ff-activex-host/

Most APIs probably work the same on WinCE, but you'll have to do some tweaking, I'm sure.